# Por qué un if se valida con i = true aunque le haya puesto i= 1 de condición?

Tags: javascript, condiciones

Estaba tratando de hacer lo más básico con un if, solo para recordar y todo eso pero se me valida ya ponga i igual a true o a 1, ¿Alguien sabe por qué es eso, es propio de js o podría ser un virus o algo así?

```
let i = true;
if (i == 1) {
    console.log("i es igual a 1");
}
 else{
    alert("i no es igual a 1");
}
```

También intenté intercambiando los valores, pero pasa lo mismo :/
Sorry si es muy obvio, pero es q soy nueva en js xxd :v :3
gracias

Comment: Que es lo que deseas saber

Comment: Antes que la locura se apodere de ti, apodérate del conocimiento: https://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/ Saludos :D

Answer (score 3):

Para entenderlo tenemos que hablar un poco de temas electronicos.

Pero no te preocupes, es facil entenderlo, mira este switch:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como podemos ver tiene dos posibles estados: `encendido` y `apagado`.

Estos estados pueden ser representados en el software y en el hardware como un valor **booleano**, o lo que es lo mismo un entero de un `bit`, recordemos que un `bit` es la unidad minima de información y la longitud maxima representable por un bit es de base `2` debido a que las computadores utilizan un sistema de información binario, esto quiere decir que en un bit solo cabe **UNO** de estos dos valores:

```
0 y 1
```

Ahora bien, electronicamente hablando, los componentes como tal solo entienden código binario, es decir, tiras largas de ceros y unos.

**Pero no pueden entender ningun otro valor**.

El interruptor visto arriba representaria por nosotros estos dos estados, donde el valor `0` haria que el sistema no deje pasar corriente, o lo que es lo mismo, dejar el interruptor hacia abajo, es decir, al no dejar pasar corriente un foco de luz por ej, nunca encenderá.

Mientras que el estado `1` o el valor `ON` o valor `true`, o dejar la palanca hacia arriba lo que haria es justo lo contrario, electronicamente activaria el circuito y dejaria pasar la energia, dandonos luz.

De hecho esta es una de las aplicaciones o representaciones mas basicas que se les puede dar a como funciona un `PC` y en general cualquier componente electronico que requiera de operaciones logicas, como por ejemplo una calculadora.

Por ej, un procesador se vale en su mayoria de solo ceros y unos para hacer todos los calculos que necesita.

Ahora bien, sabiendo este principio y de donde viene todo, los lenguajes de programacion lo unico que hacen es facilitarnos la vida un poco mas a nosotros los programadores, permitiendonos crear largas tiras de ceros y unos, o `programas` pero de una forma mas amigable, pues basicamente lo que hacen es traducir nuestro código de alto nivel a código de bajo nivel o lenguaje maquina.

> Aqui lo que mas hay que tener presente es el principio fundamental
> de que al final todo se traducira a lenguaje binario, ya
> que esto es lo unico que puede entender una computadora

Donde cualquier estado representable por un `bit` puede ser representado de "manera amigable" como un tipo más en los lenguajes de programación, en este caso un `booleano`.

Sin embargo, a nivel de compilación o interpretación, estos valores
son exactamente iguales, pues un booleano `true` es solo la
representación que nosotros como programadores le damos al numero `1`
y el valor `false` seria la representación que le damos al valor `0`
pues a nivel de hardware funcionan como tál.

Por lo que, en terminos sencillos los valores `booleanos` son solo una representación mas amigable para los programdores de un `bit` con sus correspondientes estados, es decir, un valor numerico de solo dos estados posibles.

Como curiosidad tambien podemos decir que un `booleano` es la representacion primitiva mas pequeña que puede existir (solo refiriendonos a JS), pues en otros lenguajes podemos limitar el tamaño de por ejemplo enteros, limitandolos lo suficiente como para que sean equivalentes a un booleano.

Por lo que en terminos electronicos y en terminos de software, un `booleano` y un entero del tamaño de un `bit` son lo mismo.

Sin embargo antes de que me quemen vivo debo aclarar algo mas...

`JavaScript` no es la excepcion a esta regla, pero al ser un lenguaje de tipado debil, debemos tener en cuenta la forma en como funciona, pues en `JS` podemos hacer cosas locas como esta:

```js
console.log(true == '1');
```

Donde estamos comparando directamente un `string` con un valor `booleano` y aunque no sean exactamente iguales (porque difieren en tipos) ambos son tomados por el interprete como iguales, pues lo que hace `javascript` (y otros lenguajes particulares como `PHP`) es que en una comparacion no estricta si ambos valores difieren en tipo, fuerza a uno de ellos o a ambos al valor primitivo mas cercano, es decir, convierte a uno o a ambos para que coincidan en tipo, dandonos como resultado que `true` y la cadena `"1"` son exactamente lo mismo.

Pero esto `NO` es asi en muchos lenguajes de programacion, pues en lenguajes como `Java` que son de tipado fuerte no se pueden hacer este tipo de comparaciones con objetos complejos y las comparaciones son siempre estrictas, es decir, deben coincidir en tipo e identidad (ser del mismo tipo y ser el mismo objeto o valor primitivo), sin embargo en estos lenguajes, todos tienen en comun que sus primitivos `booleanos` son exactamente iguales a ya sea el numero `0` o `1`, pues un booleano como habiamos dicho es solo una representacion de estos numeros.

En este caso entonces el problema se debe a que `JS` intenta primero convertir los valores para hacer la comparación, y es por esto que en tu ejemplo pasa algo que parece ser incorrecto:

```js
let i = true;
if (i == 1) {
    console.log("i es igual a 1");
}
 else{
    alert("i no es igual a 1");
}
```

Por lo que para solucionarlo podemos usar el operador de comparacion estricta (`===`) para que el problema se solucione y `JS` no convierta los tipos, si no que haga la comparación directamente (verificando tambien los tipos):

```js
let i = true;
if (i === 1) {
    console.log("i es igual a 1");
}
 else{
    alert("i no es igual a 1");
}
```

Como dato curioso, el hecho de que `JS` convierta los tipos dinamicamente si que tiene utilidades y no es que perjudique como tal o haga de `JS` un peor lenguaje de programacion, pues debido a que `JS` convierte los tipos podemos hacer cosas que en otros lengujes de programacion de tipado fuerte como `Java`, `C++` o incluso el mitico `python` son ilegales:

```js
const miMensaje = "Hola "  + 3 + " veces!";

console.log(miMensaje);
```

Si intentas esto mismo en casi cualquier otro lenguaje de programacion el lenguaje te crucificara, pues no puedes sumar un entero con una cadena de texto, o por lo menos tampoco puedes concatenar de esa forma.

Como prueba extra de que un `booleano` es simplemente un `bit` representable como `0` o `1` aqui te dejo una muestra en `JS`:

```js
if(1){
  console.log("Se ejecuta porque es interpretado como booleano con valor true!");
}

if(0){
  console.log("No se ejecuta porque es interpretado como valor false");
}
```

Y un ejemplo un tanto diferente pero en c++:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main()
{
    bool booleano1 = false;
    bool booleano2 = true;
    
    cout << booleano1 << endl;
    cout << booleano2 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Dandonos como resultado en la impresion de cada booleano:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]